# Asp.net Textbox cursor is confusing when using RTL layout in bootstrap

Tags: css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, textbox, right-to-left

I'm using asp.net webforms to build a website. The language is arabic so I had to use the bootstrap RTL layout. This affects the textboxes badly. The text in the text box is typed from right to left but the cursor is always at the beginning of the text not the end where it should be.

I tried to add this Css class to the textboxes to revert it to LTR layout but the problem still persists

```
.textbox-align-left {
     text-align: left !important;
}
```

Can someone help me with this?

Thank you.

EDIT
Note that the textbox is functioning properly and using the backspace button removes the last character normally. It is just the cursor that stays in the beginning of the text.

Comment: Maybe you can try 
`.textbox-fix {
     direction:rtl;
     text-align:right;
}`
Not sure if it helps.

Comment: That worked. What I tried is if you want to write arabic, combine rtl with text-align:right. If you try to type english then you should change the css to ltr and text-align:left. One of them won't work for both cases.

You should make that an answer.

Answer (score 0):

try this JS

```html
<input type="text" name="textbox" style="direction:RTL;" onkeyup="rtl(this);"/>
<script>
function rtl(element)
{   
    if(element.setSelectionRange){
        element.setSelectionRange(0,0);
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: No, that didn't work. That does the job on the surface but it messes up the order at which you can delete characters. If you type anything and try to backspace it, doesn't work.